# Допускаются ли пробелы в имени шрифта для свойства font-family?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

В [документации css-свойства `font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) написано, что

> Названия семейства шрифтов, которые содержат пробелы, должны быть взяты в кавычки

Однако приводится [пример](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81), в котором имя семейства шрифтов с пробелами не взято в кавычки:

```
font-family: Gill Sans Extrabold, sans-serif;
```

В итоге пробелы без кавычек разрешены или нет?

Answer (score 2):

На сайте консорциума World Wide Web (W3C) говорят, что:

> To avoid mistakes in escaping, it is recommended to quote font family names that contain white space, digits, or punctuation characters other than hyphens

т.е. Чтобы избежать ошибок, рекомендуется заключать в кавычки имена семейств шрифтов, которые содержат пробелы, цифры или знаки пунктуации, отличные от дефиса.

Если не поставить - в большинстве браузеров прокатит, но бывают разные случаи и разные ОС, так что я рекомендую ставить.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/

**p.s.:** Я всегда заключаю в кавычки названия семейств шрифтов, содержащих пробелы

Answer (score 2):

Открываем [спецификацию](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#family-name-value) и смотрим:

> Font family names other than generic families must either be given
> quoted as strings, or unquoted as a sequence of one or more
> identifiers. This means most punctuation characters and digits at the
> start of each token must be escaped in unquoted font family names..........

Если коротко: если в названиях присутствуют пробелы, цифры, знаки препинания или ключевые слова (например: "inherit" и другие) то **рекомендуется** брать название шрифта в двойные кавычки для избежания ошибок.